# PyQt4 Calendar Widget - highlight the 1st and 15th of each month

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Having some difficulty getting the PyQt4 Calendar Widget to have the 1st and 15th of each month highlighted. Unfortunately, there isn't much documentation on this so any help would be great. [Example: Red box around the 5th of the month every month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjUow.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must inherit from the QCalendarWidget and overwrite the paintCell method:

> QCalendarWidget.paintCell(painter, rect, date)
>
> Parameters:
>
> painter – QtGui.QPainter
>
> rect – QtCore.QRect
>
> date – QtCore.QDate

Sorry I use PyQt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication

class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):
    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        if (date.day() == 1) or (date.day() == 15):
            painter.save()
            painter.drawRect(rect)
            painter.setPen(Qt.blue)
            painter.drawText(QRectF(rect), Qt.TextSingleLine|Qt.AlignCenter, str(date.day()))
            painter.restore()
        else:
            QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!